# Additional links next to Field name?

Tags: links, datasource

I am new to develop using Sitecore and have a question

I saw in some tutorial website there are addition links next to the field name, like `[Go to field]` `[Reset Field]` `[Go to datasource]`

Is this required some modules or settings

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it's a `Sitecore Extensions` tool for browsers created by Alan Płócieniak.

> Sitecore Extensions is a google chrome/firefox extension which provides small improvements for Sitecore CMS.

You can read more about it on: https://alan-null.github.io/2016/10/sitecore-extensions-crossbrowser

You can install it for Google Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sitecore-extensions/aoclhcccfdkjddgpaaajldgljhllhgmd?hl=en

Or for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sitecore-extensions/